# How to make multiple GET request and to wait that all operations are done?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

For my app, I need to load different data from the server so I need to make couple `GET` requests. 
For each GET request, I need to save the data in my CoreData... So I need a call back, or a success block for each operation.

I tried couple things but I couldn't make it works.

When I do a single `GET` request :

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/actors", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL]] parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  // Core Data saving
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

How to make multiple `GET` and to wait that all my requests are done ?

If someone writes me a solution... Does it works for other type of requests ? (POST, DELETE, PUT... etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution with `AFNetworking`, and I could do exactly what I wanted to do :

```
NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
        NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", numberOfFinishedOperations, totalNumberOfOperations);
    } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
        [self.delegate dataRefreshingDone];
    }];
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

It will execute all my `GET` operations one by one. 
I made a special `getter` to create an operation according a `url` .

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operationGetForUrl:(NSString *)url
{
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/%@", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL], url]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:    [operation.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"]];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       // YOUR SUCCESS BLOCK
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       // FAILURE BLOCK
    }];
    return operation;
}
```

So as you see, for each operation, I have a success block, its possible to make some generic things ... Or you can make specifics operation getter.

Comment: I could be wrong but be aware that 'batchOfRequestOperations' does not work with the newer 'AFURLSessionManager' classes of AFNetworking2.

Answer (score 3):

A `dispatch_group` could be one possible solution while maintaining an incredibly generic structure and will also work with any kind of request you want.

Instead of recreating a good example, [commandshift has a good writeup explaining them and a great example of how to use them](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/19/using-dispatch-groups-to-wait-for-multiple-web-services/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I hope you found the article helpful!

Answer (score 2):

The `AFHTTPRequestOperation` class is a subclass of `AFURLConnectionOperation` which provides the method

```
+ (NSArray *)batchOfRequestOperations:(NSArray *)operations progressBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations , NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations ))progressBlock completionBlock:(void ( ^ ) ( NSArray *operations ))completionBlock
```

This method takes an `NSArray` of operations and two blocks, one for updating progress (if needed) and the other to be called upon completion. This method takes care of the completion group / completion queue dance you would have to do manually. Once the operations are finished, the completion block is called and you can cycle through the operations using properties of `AFHTTPRequestOperation` and `AFURLConnectionOperation` to grab the response data and save it to your Core Data objects.

You can create your operations as follows:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operation.responseSerializer = // set the serializer if you need something other than JSON
```

You can set the completion block property as well if you'd like to store the response object's in private properties and then access them in the completion block where you would then save them to your Core Data objects. This would simplify the logic required in the completion block.

In order to have the operations run you need to create an NSOperationQueue and add the operations. It would go as follows:

```
NSArray *operations = @[op1, op2, op3...];
NSOperationQueue *downloadQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[downloadQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

### Updated Answer

In that case, you can probably write a more generic method that recursively go through an array containing your request path:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// Header file
// --------------------------------------------------------
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrRequestURLs;

// --------------------------------------------------------
// Implementation file
// --------------------------------------------------------
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    self.arrRequestURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [self.arrRequestURLS addObject:@[@"http://api.myserver.com/api/actors"];
    [self.arrRequestURLS addObject:@[@"http://api.myserver.com/api/directors"];
    [self.arrRequestURLS addObject:@[@"http://api.myserver.com/api/photographers"];

    [self performRequestQueue:self.arrRequestURLS onSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        // all request completed successfully do something here

    } onFailure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to complete all request");
    } onEachSuccess: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id *responseObject, NSString *sourceRequestURL) {

        // Scroll down to bottom see method implementation
        [self handleIntermediateSuccessOperation:operation 
                                      Response:responseObject 
                              ForRequestURL:sourceRequestURL];
    }];
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A recursive method that executes each request string in the passed in array
// and removes from array after successfully performing request, then calls itself
// again until arrRequestURLs is empty.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)performRequestQueue:(NSMutableArray *)arrRequestURLs 
                 onSuccess:(void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success 
                 onFailure:(void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
                 onEachSuccess: (void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id *responseObject, NSString *sourceRequestURL))intermediateSuccess
{
    if(arrRequestURLs.count > 0)
    {
        // make request
        [manager GET:arrRequestURLs[0] parameters:nil 
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

           // call intermediate success block if any
           if(intermediateSuccess)
           {
               intermediateSuccess(operation, responseObject, arrRequestURLs[0]);
           }

           // remove the current str from array
           [arrRequestURLs removeObjectAtIndex:0];

            // check to see if there more request
            if(arrRequestURLs.count > 0)
            {
                // recursively call this method again to perform next URL string from array
                [self performRequestQueue:arrRequestURLs onSuccess:success onFailure:failure];
            }
            else
            {
                // no more request in arrRequestURLs, call finish block if any
                if(success)
                {
                    success(operation, responseObject);
                }
            }           
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            if(failure)
            {
                failure(operation, error);
            }
        }];
    }
}


// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// This method here handles the in-between success block for each operation
// including the last final success block.
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-(void)handleIntermediateSuccessOperation:(AFHTTPRequestOperation *)operation 
                                          Response:(id)responseObject
                                  ForRequestURL:(NSString *)sourceRequestURL
{
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Alternative, you can probably use a for loop here to get the
    // matching array index from self.arrRequestURLs and use it.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    if([sourceRequestURL isEqualToString:self.arrRequestURLs[0]])
    {
        // success block for actors, do something here
    }
    else if([sourceRequestURL isEqualToString:self.arrRequestURLs[1]])
    {
        // success block for directors, do something here
    }
    else
    {
        // success block for photographers, do something here
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

You can chain your request:

```
[manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/actors", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL]] parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  // Core Data saving

    [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/directors", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL]] parameters:nil 
    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      // Core Data saving


        [manager GET:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/api/photographers", [NSString stringWithUTF8String:kBaseURL]] parameters:nil 
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          // Core Data saving

            // ---------------------------------------------
            // Finished downloading all data
            // do something here 
            // ---------------------------------------------


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: That solution seems to be the most appropriate but there are not any other ways ? I mean... If we want to make something generic... If I want to add or remove any request, It would be great to just add an operation, or I don't know. If I need to do around 10 requests... That solution will make the file unreadable Right ?

Comment: the problem is that I can't make a unique success for each operation. 
It would be great to have an array of operation... Each operation would have a success block...

Comment: Have added extra code to handle intermediate success blocks.

Comment: Hi @Zhang, Look at my new answer. I think it's pretty nice solution

Comment: Whatever floats the boat :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would have only few requests you could nest next operations inside success blocks. If you would have more operations than few I suggest you to use NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    NSInteger successCount;

AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:someUrl parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  successCount++;
  if(successCount == 3){
     //do stuff
  }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[manager GET:someUrl parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  successCount++;
  if(successCount == 3){
     //do stuff
  }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];

[manager GET:someUrl parameters:nil 
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  successCount++;
  if(successCount == 3){
     //do stuff
  }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```